# SQL Server backup fails with network UNC share

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, backup, database-backups

I am currently trying to take backup of a database to a network UNC share, but its giving me error.

I have two PCs connected in a simple NETWORK, not a domain.
From both pcs, I can easily create and edit files on either one.

One PC on which SQL SERVER is running and database files are located, is named `SERVER`.

Another PC on which I want to take backup, is named `STUDENT-PC2`. On this pc, `drive d:` is a shared drive and I set the full permission for this folder for `Everyone, IUSER,NETWORK,NETWORK SERVICE`

When I run following command from SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO on SERVER, it throws me error as below.

I am running sql server service as `NETWORK SERVICE`

**COMMAND**

```
backup database dpmt to disk='\\STUDENT-PC2\d\DPMT_BACKUP_17032016_102719.Bak'
```

**ERROR**

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot open backup device '\\STUDENT-PC2\d\DPMT_BACKUP_17032016_102719.Bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: Does the user running the SQL server process have write permission to the share?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson How can i add `NETWORK SERVICE` to share folder permission section?I have added `NETWORK SERVICE` account of `STUDENT-PC2` with full permission for `drive d:` on `STUDENT-PC2`.

Comment: Try adding write permission on the share for the computer account for STUDENT-PC2$.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I dont get this, Can you describe how to do this?

Comment: You need to check the permissions (both sharing and file system) on the server. How to do that is a bit out of scope for this site, [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) is probably a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

On computer "STUDENT-PC2" locate the file share that is destination for backups. In file share permissions add account named as your SQL machine plus dollar sign, like this: "SERVER$" - type that instead of username. Tick write+read permissions for that artificial "user", and hit OK to close. On the file system level configure permissions the same (write+read) or let Everyone write at first to test and then reduce.
In summary:

- if both computers are not part of the same domain, the other computer (STUDENT-PC2) sees all local accounts from "SERVER" as "SERVER$" account, no matter what they real name is.
- you need to set permissions on destination (STUDENT-PC2) for account "SERVER$" at two levels: file share permission level, and ntfs file system permission level.